# .babelrc file is not applied

Tags: webpack, babel-loader

I want to use ts only as a form for type-check, so I use babel-loader and add only typescript-preset as shown below. It is not applied when writing the .babelrc file, but it is applied only if you give the option inside the babel-loader inside the webpack.config.js file like this. When I read the official documentation, I understood that babel-loader automatically recognizes and applies the .babelrc file. Am I wrong?

[myRepo](https://github.com/Dailyscat/lcp-common-window-dialog)

.babelrc

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
      "plugins": []
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "targets": { "ie": 11 }
          }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
      ],
      "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", { "corejs": 3 }]]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What versions of babel-core and babel-loader are you using? You might be running into this bug: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that can go wrong and without direct access to your setup it's pretty hard to rule simple things out (like `.babelrc` being in the wrong directory).

However, if you are running babel-loader version 7.1.1 or earlier, then it's very possible that you've run into a [bug](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/552) where `babel.transform` did not read the `.babelrc` file correctly by default.

There are two solutions:

#### Solution 1: Upgrade babel-loader to 7.1.2+

The bug was patched in 7.1.2 and 7.1.4 onward.

#### Solution 2: Add `babelrc: true` to your webpack options

If you can't upgrade for some reason, then you simply need to explicitly tell `babel.transform` to look for a babel config file:

```js
  //...
  {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      babelrc: true,
    }
  }
  // ...
```

Comment: thank you!! It's been a big help. 
I am using the latest version of babel-loader, so it did not match solution 1, but I set it myself as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found two ways to solve the same, which finally amount to the same think:

**Mention contents of .babelrc directly in webpack config**

```
  module: {
  
    rules:[
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options:{
                        "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
                        "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
                    },
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
        }
    ]
  
  }
```

**Load the contents of the .babelrc and pass the object as options**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const babelrcx = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '.babelrc'))
let babelrc = JSON.parse(babelrcx)

module: {
  
    rules:[
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: babelrc,
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
        }
    ]
  
  }
```

**NOTE:** For this to work the .babelrc needs to be in the directory of webpack config file (e.g. build directory)

*This solution was mentioned in some stackoverflow post but I am not able to track it currently.*